# Rails migration inheritance not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, migration

I have a base class for a type of migration that occurs frequently:

```
class AddEventsBaseMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  #ITEMS = []

  def up
    #add the items
  end

  def down
    #remove the items that were added.
  end
end
```

Then, when it's time to add new stuff, I create an inherited migration:

```
class AddEvents0930 < AddEventsBaseMigration  
  ITEMS = [ ... ]
end
```

When I try to run this migration, I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant AddEventsBaseMigration
C:/.../Source/db/migrate/20131002152826_add_events_0930.rb:1
c:0:in `migrate'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate:up
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**Ruby:** 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [i386-mingw32]

**Rails:** 3.2.13

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that I've tried:

```
require "add_events_base_migration"
require "./add_events_base_migration"
require "/db/migrate/add_events_base_migration"
```

And I get the error: `no such file to load -- /db/migrate/add_events_base_migration`

Comment: Maybe you need to explicitly add `require './add_events_base_migration'` or `require '/db/migrations/add_events_base_migration'` at the beginning of the file ?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I've tried that.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
require_relative "add_events_base_migration"
```

For example, if you have unit test classes in the "test" directory, and data for them under the test "test/data" directory, then you might use a line like this in a test case:

```
require_relative "data/customer_data_1"
```

If you're on Ruby 1.8, you might need to use this library:

https://github.com/steveklabnik/require_relative

Comment: I just tried it and I get `undefined method 'require_relative' for main:Object` ... ?

Comment: Why would I have to do that to inherit from another class? Is this not built-in to ruby/rails?

Comment: `require_relative` is built into Ruby 1.9.2 and later. If you're getting `undefined method 'require_relative'` it's probably because you're using an older version of Ruby. See: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Kernel.html

Comment: FYI the inheritance still does not work. Still getting this error: `uninitialized constant`

Comment: (It works as in the file is located fine, but the inheritance portion still does not work. I'm working around that for now.